# How do I route incoming requests to specific apps based on IP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

How would I route requests to different IIS apps based on the user's IP address?

I'm looking to pilot a test version of a production site to a specific IP address.  I would rather not have to force these users to access a separate URL.  So, I'm asking if there is a way within IIS to force the server to process the request via a secondary app based on the requesting user's IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible on IIS 7+ using application request routing:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing